# Primefaces timeline blink on update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces timeline blinking on update. This is very unaesthetic older version did not blink on update.
If you click on button in primefaces showcase you can see how it looks like:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/editServer.xhtml?jfwid=0a833

```
        <p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{editServerTimelineView.model}" var="booking"
                zoomMax="#{editServerTimelineView.zoomMax}"
                start="#{editServerTimelineView.start}"
                end="#{editServerTimelineView.end}"
                editable="true" editableTime="#{editServerTimelineView.editableTime}"
                widgetVar="timelineWdgt">


        <p:commandButton value="Toggle TimeChangeable" process="@this" update="timeline" 
                     action="#{editServerTimelineView.toggleEditableTime}"/>
```

The same thing happen when ever you update timeline.

**Do you know how to prevent blinking of timeline?**

Comment: Hmmm this is most likely updating to upgrading the timeline to a newer version of the plugin.

Comment: Also the example has this facet which is supposed to show you its loading `<f:facet name="loading">
                <i class="pi pi-spin pi-spinner" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
            </f:facet>` but it does not appear to be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the blink on update occurs on lazy load and in the new items.
It's possible, and it's not due to doing more work. It's a design decision, a change of visibility in the dom object, when rendering the component in js just before load the loadingScreen you can see:

```
p.dom.root.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

monkey patching timeline.js and changing to

```
p.dom.root.style.visibility = "visible";
```

the problem dissapear.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how did you change it? Did you change directly the timeline.js in primefaces package?

Comment: I Monkey Patched timeline.js.  That is, I extract timeline.js from the package, unminify it and load in my web application, wherever I use the timeline in the xhtml i import de modified js   from my server: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/timeline/timeline.js"></script><code/`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the new timeline does more work when rendering and has lots of new features but this is a side effect. They offer the loading screen template to let your users know its loading like..

```xml
<f:facet name="loading">
   <h1>Loading please wait...</h1>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: So it is not possible to avoid it. Also an answer.